# How do i merge multiple lists of string arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, stream

I'm working in Java and I have three lists consisting of arrays filled with strings (List) of which I've made streams. The first list contains multiple arrays with two strings inside (let's call them COUNTRY, and CITY). The second list has the same format but consists of CITY and ROAD, and then the final list contains arrays with 5 strings (ROAD, A, B, C, and D).

What I need to do is merge these three lists into one where each COUNTRY is linked to every ROAD based on the CITY value if they match, and then add all the data we have from each ROAD.

So for example going from:

```
List1: ["COUNTRY1", "CITY1"], [...]
List2: ["CITY1", "ROAD1"], [...]
List3: ["ROAD1", "A", "B", "C", "D"], [...]
```

to:

```
output: ["COUNTRY1", "CITY1", "ROAD1", "A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

it is important to note that each country appears multiple times with different cities, and each city appears multiple times with different roads, sometimes multiple cities share the same road, but in the list of arrays with 5 strings, each road is unique.

tl;dr :

I need to merge all roads and their data to cities they're associated with, and to countries associated with those cities. I'm completely new to Java but I was told Streams are the way to go since my data contains a couple of dozen GBs.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Your data cries to be stored in RDB

Comment: Please paste code you have tried.

Comment: Are you sure you have enough memory to fit all your data? What you planing to do with result?

Comment: You could use HashSet data structure. It has useful methods to find union,intersection or set difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay in pure Java convert your lists to `java.util.Map` each and use countries, cities and roads as keys. Then you can do what you verbally described and iterate over List3 for example and pick the missing values from the aforementioned maps.

Comment: But would that still be possible when each key occurs multiple times in the same list? for example in list1 each country has multiple cities and sometimes cities with the same name appear in a different country.

Comment: That is a problem that Java won't solve for you (nor any other programming language). If city is not unique the relation to road is not unique either. You output example implies that you want to relate country to city to roads.

List1: `["USA", "Paris"], ["France", Paris"]`
List2: `["Paris", "X"], ["Paris", "Y"]`

If you can't tell if X is in USA or in France a computer can't either (based on this data set)

Comment: 1) Map<Country, listOfCities>, 2) Map<city, listOfRoads>.... Traverse or print accordingly.